# Programmatically Insert Multiple Rows into SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a doctor database. I want to insert data into the database from the code itself, but I cannot figure out how to insert multiple rows into the database. Can someone please help me with the syntax? I have a list of 30 doctors.

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Doctor extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
SQLiteDatabase db;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor);
    TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    String doc= getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
    String authentication= getIntent().getStringExtra("auth");
    textView.setText(doc);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("DoctorDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doctor(Name VARCHAR,degree VARCHAR,address VARCHAR,phnumber VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO 'DoctorDB' ('Name', 'degree','address', 'phnumber')VALUES ('"Sujoy Khan"')");
}
```

Comment: you should iterate over your data and insert it row by row, or insert them all in one transaction in case you want to abort the query when one fail

Answer (score 0):

create placeholder for the query:

```
String placeholder = "INSERT INTO 'DoctorDB' ('Name', 'degree','address', 'phnumber')VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')";
```

And then in cycle use `String.format()` to replace `%s` with actual values:

```
for(...) {
    String sql = String.format (placeholder, name, degree, address, phnumber);
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Comment: I am a novice in android programming. Can you please answer two queries for me regarding your code?
1. the for loop you gave has no condition is it going to be like that ?
2. do i write the string placeholder statement every time for a new row entry? 
3. if i need to write the placeholder statement multiple times do i need to write the for loop once?

Comment: @PurushottamMukhopadhyay, 1) you have to create your own conditions according to the way you store your `list of 30 doctors`. Only you know how you store them. 2) no, it is a constant. It will be the same for all queries (for all doctors).

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use methods `beginTransaction()`, `setTransactionSuccessful()` and `endTransaction()` for bulk operations. You need first a `SQLiteDatabase` instance, and using `ContentValues` you'll insert all the needed information in the database. An example would be:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = DbOpenHelper.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
database.beginTransaction();

for (Doctor doctor : doctors) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Name", doctor.name);
    contentValues.put("Degree", doctor.degree);

    database.insert(TABLE_DOCTOR, null, contentValues);
}

database.setTransactionSuccessful();
database.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where to insert your code ? I am a novice in Android programming. Also do i just go on writing contentValues.put("Name", doctor.name)? and so on to go to next row? Also am I right in assuming that I put the name of the doctor in place of "Name"?